# According to Jehovah's Witnesses, what are the essential features of a true follower of Christ, and can such be found in other denominations?

Tags: soteriology, terminology, jehovahs-witnesses, christian-living, comparative-christianity

Not much to add to the title. I would like to know the Jehovah's Witnesses' definition of a true follower of Christ, that is to say, what features are considered by them to be essential for a person to be qualified as such. And as a follow-up question, I would like to know if they believe that these essential features can be found outside of Jehovah's Witnesses, in Christians from other denominations or groups.

**Note**: By true follower of Christ I mean whatever Jehovah's Witnesses mean by someone who is walking the narrow path that leads to salvation, according to the perfect will of God, following the example set by Jesus Christ.

Comment: While you are waiting for an answer here is a good resource for a starter. https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/enjoy-life-forever/section-2/lesson-18/

Comment: @Kris I follow and do everything in the little booklet you referenced including loving others according to John 13:34-35. I also attend a Protestant non-denominational Church named Calvary Chapel. Do I qualify as a "true" Christian according to you and your organization, the Jehovah's Witnesses?

Comment: @Mr.Bond You would likely not be considered a true Christian because JWs believe most people who profess to be Christian follow tradition rather than basing their beliefs in the Bible. The Trinity, immortality of the soul, and hellfire are 3 of such beliefs that JWs would say are based on pagan tradition. They also define true Christians based on how they have love among an international brotherhood that transcends nationalism, racism, or tribalism. They refuse to support war or the military of any nation. And thirdly, a true Christian engages in the preaching work. Does that describe you?

Comment: @4castle I base all my beliefs on the Bible, period. And who told you the Trinity, immortality of the soul, and hellfire are pagan beliefs? Give me the sources you learned that from? I also (as I said to Kris) love people for Christ sake no matter their ethnicity, background or color. Acts 17:26, "God has made of one blood all the peoples of the earth." And this is a biggie that does disqualify me. I spent 1968 in Vietnam right at the start of the Tet offensive and God brought me through it so I could spend the rest of my days in preaching the true Jesus Christ, not Michael the arc angel.

Comment: @Mr.Bond asked "*who told you the Trinity, immortality of the soul, and hellfire are pagan beliefs? Give me the sources you learned that from?*".  Almost any encyclopedia will confirm this.  But the point is, the Bible *doesn't* support these beliefs.  So the real question is, "who told you the Trinity, immortality of the soul, and hellfire are biblical beliefs?".

Comment: @RayButterworth Oh I don't know! Off the top of my head the immortality of the soul you have. Psalm 22:26, 23:6, 49:7-9, Ecclesiastes 12:7, Daniel 12:2-3, Matthew 25:46, 1 Corinthians 15:12-19, Daniel 12:2 and Matthew 25:46. How about "hellfire?" Here's about a hundred verses, https://www.openbible.info/topics/eternal_damnation_in_hell Do any of your encyclopedia's have these verses? The Trinity, hmmn. In the Bible ONLY three persons are identified as God by, His names, His titles, His unique actions and His worship. Guess who those three persons are? The Father, Son and the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, I wasn't questioning the word "hellfire" itself, which is obviously quite biblical, but the concept of a place where immortal souls are tortured forever. Your "damnation" link is quotations about destruction, not torture.  E.g. 3:16 says "*… should not perish but have everlasting life*". Notice the contrast between "life" and "perish". "Perish" means destruction, not a conscious life of suffering, otherwise that too would be an everlasting life.

Comment: @Mr.Bond, I don't understand that list of scriptures about the immortality of the soul. They all talk about hoping for an eternal life, or about the difference between an eternal life and and an eternal death, and are good support against the idea of immortal souls.

Comment: Related.    https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/64024/23657

Comment: @Mr.Bond, God's holy spirit appears to be identified as a person mostly because the English translators chose to capitalize the two words and to use English masculine pronouns rather than "it", because of their pre-existing belief in the Trinity doctrine (eisegesis).  Such a translation would not have occurred to anyone that didn't already know about that doctrine (exegesis).

Comment: @RayButterworth I see you quoted part of John 3:16 and then contrasted the words "life" and "perish." Where do people end up being "perished" to? Yes, are body's are destroyed but not our spirit. Ecclesiastes 12:7, "Then shall the dust return to the earth as it was; and the spirit shall return to God who gave it." So eventually what do you think happens at the end of the age/world? Jesus Christ gave us a picture at Luke 16:19-31. https://biblehub.com/luke/16-24.htm Is this the place you want to end up in? And about the person of the Holy Spirit please read Acts 5:3-4, only one of many examples

Comment: @Mr.Bond  quotes "*the spirit shall return to God who gave it*".
That spirit is the spirit of life, not a spirit of eternal life.
The same word (רוּחַ, rûaḥ, H7307) is used in Genesis 7:15 "*And they went into the ark to Noah, two by two, of all flesh in which is the breath[spirit] of life.*".
If Ecclesiastes 12:7 is proof of eternal life in man, then it is also just as much proof of eternal life for all breathing animals.
Do you believe that all the animals will be granted salvation too?

Comment: @Mr.Bond, you are expressing an idea and then quoting specific scriptures that support it.
That is a perfectly good thing to do when discussing it with others that share it, or when reconfirming your beliefs.
It is known as *eisegesis*.
¶ But if you are trying to prove the idea to someone that doesn't already believe it, it won't work.
To convince someone else, *exegesis* is needed: give the quotations first, and then show how they naturally lead to the idea.
¶ In this case, the three doctrines *can't* be derived by exegesis, so it is very difficult to prove them to non-believers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to this official Jehovah’s Witness article **How to Identify Real Christians** (provided by Kris) is useful as the basis for exploring how Jehovah’s Witnesses view Christians from other denominations: https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/enjoy-life-forever/section-2/lesson-18/

At first glance the article appears non-contentious then asks: SOME PEOPLE SAY: “Christians have done terrible things—how can they have the true religion?”  The article concludes with this SUMMARY: Real Christians follow Bible teachings, show self-sacrificing love, and preach Bible truth.

This is where the discerning reader needs to drill down to get to the truth.  This article, **How False Religion Misrepresents God** is more forthcoming: https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/enjoy-life-forever/section-2/lesson-13/

> If God is love, why have so many evil acts been committed by religions that claim to represent him? ***Put simply, these religions are false; they misrepresent God.***

> 1. How does false religion misrepresent God by its teachings?  False religion has “exchanged the truth of God for the lie.” (Romans 1:25) For example, most religions ***have not taught their followers God’s name.*** However, the Bible says that God’s name must be used. (Romans 10:13, 14) Some religious leaders say that when something terrible happens, it is God’s will. But that is a lie. God is never the source of evil. (Read James 1:13.) Sadly, religious lies have pushed people away from God.

> 2. How does false religion misrepresent God by its actions?  False religion does not treat people as Jehovah does. The Bible says that false religion’s “sins have massed together clear up to heaven.” (Revelation 18:5) For centuries, religions have ***meddled in politics, supported wars, and caused or approved the death of countless numbers of people.*** Some religious leaders enjoy a lavish lifestyle and demand money from their followers to pay for it. These actions prove that they do not even know God, let alone have the right to represent him.—Read 1 John 4:8.

> 3. How does God feel about false religion?  If the things done by false religion make you angry, how do you think Jehovah feels? He loves people, but he is angry with religious leaders who misrepresent him and mistreat their followers. He promises that false religion will be destroyed and “will never be found again.” (Revelation 18:21) ***Soon, God will put an end to all false religion.***—Revelation 18:8.

> 5. False religion does not reflect God’s love: Religions have misrepresented God in many ways. ***One notorious way has been their involvement in war.***

> **SUMMARY: False religion has misrepresented God by means of its false teachings and terrible practices. God will destroy false religion.**

Jehovah’s Witnesses believe this will happen at Armageddon and only dedicated, faithful and obedient Jehovah’s Witnesses will survive.  They believe virtually every person who has died before Armageddon will be resurrected with a physical body and be given an opportunity to be saved during the millennial reign of Christ Jesus, from heaven, over the inhabitants of a paradise earth.

For the avoidance of any doubt, it is important to understand that Jehovah’s Witnesses believe ***every Trinitarian Christian denomination is part of the Antichrist:***

> What about today? People and organizations making up the antichrist still oppose Christ and his teachings. They deliberately spread lies and deceptions with the intent of confusing the identity of the Father, Jehovah God, and of His Son, Jesus Christ. We have good reason to beware of such religious deceptions. Let us look at two examples.

> For centuries, the churches propagated the doctrine of the Trinity, claiming that the Father and the Son are part of the same entity. The antichrist thus shrouds in mystery the identity of Jehovah God and Jesus Christ. This mystery hinders sincere people from imitating Jesus Christ and drawing close to God, as the Bible encourages them to.—1 Corinthians 11:1; James 4:8.

> The churches add to the confusion by promoting the use of Bible translations that omit God’s personal name, Jehovah, from the text. They do this despite the fact that the name Jehovah occurs some 7,000 times in the original text of the Bible. The result? The identity of the true God becomes even more shrouded in mystery.

> For centuries, the antichrist has kept millions in spiritual darkness. But by studying God’s Word, the Bible, we are able to learn the true identity of the antichrist and be set free from the antichrist’s religious lies and deceptions.—John 17:17.
> Source: https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/wp20150601/who-is-the-antichrist/

Those are some (but not all) of the essential features of a true follower of Christ according to Jehovah’s Witnesses.  True followers of Christ denounce the Trinity, actively promote the name Jehovah, and they will have nothing to do with “Christendom” because of “its false teachings and terrible practices. God will destroy false religion.”

Jehovah’s Witnesses believe they, and only they, have the “truth” and that they are Jehovah’s sole appointed earthly organisation.  Even Christian denominations that reject the Trinity doctrine fail because they do not promote the name Jehovah in their Bibles, and are not baptised Witnesses of Jehovah.  They are all, without exception, part of “false religion”, soon to be destroyed at Armageddon.

This link provides access to other related articles: https://www.jw.org/en/search/?q=antichrist

Comment: +1 There's plenty of Churches claiming that they have it right (or more right) than others.  Jesus is the way and He builds the Church.  "Unless you believe that I am (he) you will die in your sins."

Answer (score 0):

Jehovah's Witnesses consider themselves to be the true and *only* organization to bring about salvation.

They consider the rest of Christianity to be *false*, the main reason for this, and the main distinguishing factor is, Jehovah's Witnesses reject the *Trinity* (most Christian denominations accept).

Their criteria to get to heaven is to be a member in good standing, to be baptized. Essentially, to believe their message and "dedicate" your life to Jehovah God. Going to their worship service, reading the Bible, sharing the message to others, avoiding sin, etc.

You can see how their rejection of the Trinity *makes* for a good case in saying other *creeds* have fallen into idolatry. Coming from the *Millerite movement*, they also reject the doctrine of *eternal hell*, in favor of *Christian moralism* (the wicked will be destroyed). [Source for baptism](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/what-is-baptism/)

Comment: 1 For vast majority of JWs heaven is not the reward for Faithful life course.     2 We dedicate our lives to Jehovah not Jesus.   3 although  Charles Russel and Miller crossed paths early on JWs are not millerite affiliated    See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/60274/23657

Comment: Actually  Russell was born after miller’s death so they did not meet.  Another early restorationist named Storrs who Russell was associated with crossed paths with miller briefly.

Comment: "to believe their message and 'dedicate' your life to Jesus." Actually, we dedicate our lives to Jehovah since he is our Creator and Life-Giver.

Comment: @Kris thank you, I edited that to Jehovah God, instead of Jesus. Please don't take my response as biased in  any way, I very much respect Jehovah's witnesses. I guess I was just trying to point out everyone wants to get to heaven. Thanks for you comment! Hope my edit helps!

Comment: @agarza That is correct, I was so used to the expression that it slipped, again I meant no disrespect, I've edited that to point Jehovah God.

Comment: Actually, most Jehovah’s Witnesses don’t hope to go to heaven. We believe that the earth will be restored to a paradise, and we hope to live there forever. (Psalm 37:29) But Christ has been selecting 144,000 individuals who will rule as kings and priests in heaven, serving to help Christ to restore the earth to a paradise during the first 1000 years after Armageddon.